# function for button creation is not working properly

Tags: python, math

so im trying to make a petri-net simulation tool and this function is supposed to create the buttons for transitions and enable me to click them to fire the transition therefore adding and deleting the appropriate markings .its is functional but I have 2 problems that I dunno how to solve

1. If i add more than on button the previous buttons cant be clicked
2. every time i fire the transition the new updated graph pops up in a new window rather than the same graph being updated

   ```
            def create_transition_buttons(num_transitions, markings_vector, incidence_matrix, ax, fig, G=None, num_places=None):
                buttons = []
                button_width = 0.1
                button_gap = 0.02

                def on_button_click(event):
                    nonlocal markings_vector, incidence_matrix, buttons

                    # Get the index of the fired transition
                    button_index = buttons.index(event.inaxes)

                    # Check if the transition can be fired
                    if np.all(incidence_matrix[:, button_index] != -1) or np.all(markings_vector[incidence_matrix[:, button_index] == -1] > 0):
                        # Update the markings vector
                        #markings_vector = markings_vector + np.dot(incidence_matrix, np.eye(num_transitions)[:, button_index][:, np.newaxis])

                                # Modify markings of places
                        modified = [False] * num_places
                        for i in range(num_places):
                            if incidence_matrix[i, button_index] == 1 and not modified[i]:
                                markings_vector[i] += 1
                                modified[i] = True
                        for i in range(num_places):    
                            if incidence_matrix[i, button_index] == -1 and not modified[i]:
                                markings_vector[i] -= 1
                                modified[i] = True

                        # Redraw the Petri net graph with the new markings
                        ax.clear()
                        print('buttonbugman')
                        draw_petri_net_graph(G, num_places, num_transitions, markings_vector, incidence_matrix)
                        plt.show()
                        print('buttonbugman2')
                        #fig.canvas.draw_idle()

                for i in range(num_transitions):
                    button_x = 0.05 + i * (button_width + button_gap)
                    button_y = 0.05
                    button_label = f"Fire T{i+1}"
                    button_ax = plt.axes([button_x, button_y, button_width, 0.05])
                    button = plt.Button(button_ax, button_label)
                    button.on_clicked(on_button_click)
                    buttons.append(button_ax)

                plt.show()
                print('bugman2')

                return buttons
   ```

i tried messing with the plot.show() but anything other than this layout will result in some messed up output